# Pyqt5 extended image annotation graph

Tags: pyqt5, annotations, polygon, interactive, pyqt6

I am trying to annotate an image with a multiple closed cells like structure. New to PyQt so
I found this straightforeward nice code from eyllanesc here:

[PyQT User Editable Polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52751121/pyqt-user-editable-polygons)

I need to extend this, so that I can add further polylines to the first polygon with mouse clicks. These should start and end at existing nodes from the first poly.
At the end I would like to retrieve the points and edges from this multi poly object.

Could I do this with QGraphicsPoligonItem? Seems to be always closed .. Or do I need to switch to QPainterPath? And how..

Any advise would be helpfull..

Comment: That link is for a profile page. Besides, as you already found out, QGraphicsPolygonItem uses closes polygons, so if you need "open" paths, you can only use QGraphicsPathItem.

Comment: Sorry! Now the right link.